# Customize "more" tab on TabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

As you know, if the number of tab exceeds 5, the iPhone adds a tab called "more".

My question is:

How can we do to customize this tab, change its title or even the view ? My initial View controller is a tab bar controller.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class(or say category) by inheriting tab bar controller class & you can control the things as required.

- Create a class inheriting TabBarController.
- Add your own view inside init method.
- Handle the selection event as your super class is TabBarController.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to change the title of the editButtonItem like this : `self.moreNavigationController.editButtonItem.title = @"Modifier";` but it didn't work :/

Comment: Instead why don't you make a button and assign the button to more tab!! I haven't tried this but might help you.